# What is missing?

Tags: android, smali

Good day! I've been trying to add a simple GET Request for logging purposes manually to an App I'm trying to hunt bugs for. And yes it sounds stupid but I'm doing it for a bet with my pal haha.

I've tried 3 approaches so far:

1. using java.net
2. using okhttpclient

```
.method public final IVS(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    .registers 5

    iput-object p1, p0 Lpackage;->Ihavevalue:Ljava/lang/String;
    
    new-instance v0, Ljava/net/URL;
    
    const-string v1, "http://SomeUrl"
    
    invoke-direct {v0, v1}, Ljava/net/URL;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    
    const-string v1, "GET"
    
    invoke-virtual {v0}, Ljava/net/URL;->openConnection()Ljava/net/URLConnection;
    
# There's some check-cast I see here.. but decided to omit it is it important?

    move-result-object v0
    
    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Ljava/net/HttpURLConnection;->setRequestMethod(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    
    invoke-virtual {v0}, Ljava/net/URLConnection;->connect()V

    return-void
.end-method
```

When I save the dex file and run it to jadx,

here is what it outputs, and just looks so wrong

````
/* JADX WARN: Type inference failed for: r0v1, types: [java.net.URL, void] */
    /* JADX WARN: Type inference failed for: r0v2, types: [java.net.URLConnection, java.net.URL] */
public final void IVS(String str) {
    ?? r0;
    this.Ihavevalue = str;
    new URL("http://site");
    r0.openConnection().openStream();
}```

I'm really close to pulling my hair out and might just do if it's just a simple syntax/sequence thinggy missed with smali. Hope someone can help, thank you.
````

Comment: ```public final void a(String str) {
        this.ihavevalue = str;
        URL url = new URL("http://13.215.238.141/dec.php");
        url.openStream();
        url.close();
    }```

I was able to get this result with when running the dex to jadx..

However it won't send any request. Is there something wrong?

Comment: Just a connect wont make any sense